# What is this aircraft seen at Peachtree City, GA?

Tags: general-aviation, aircraft-identification, jet

[image]

Sorry for the poor quality, but this jet was taking off from Peachtree City Regional on Sunday 13 May. Anyone know the aircraft?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's one of many privately owned [Aero L-39s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aero_L-39_Albatros), some of which are [in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Aero_L-39_Albatros_operators#_United_States). Here's one [registered](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?NNumbertxt=915WE) in Georgia, USA, with a similar livery at the same airport:

[image]
([flickr.com](https://www.flickr.com/photos/aberdeenrails/38537448165/in/photolist-21HquHt-233PNYK)) N915WE.

> **N915WE Aero L39C**
>   Preparing for takeoff. Falcon Field-Peachtree City, Ga.

It could actually be the same one you photographed.

Comment: Are those also privately owned AIM-9 Sidewinders under the privately owned wings there?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri - they're as real as this being a [USAF L-39](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Untitled/Aero-L-39-Albatros/4184527) ;)

Comment: I know you have unusually lenient gun laws in the USA but this is ridiculous! (kidding, kidding)

Comment: FYI, I have asked a [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/51557/18187) about those missiles.

Comment: I don't think it's the OP's plane - the Slovak emblem would be visible (unless it's only painted on one side of the tail).